# providing optional param to injectable service constructor - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router-params

There is AppComponent and SecurityService.

```
...
@Injectable()
export class SecurityService implements OnInit {    
    private _url: string;

    constructor(private http: Http, private name?: string) {
        this._wsUrl = 'http://myurl/' + this.name        
    }
...
}
```

AppComponent is one which will inject security service.

```
export class App {

    constructor(private security: SecurityService){

    }
    ... 
}
```

> My question is: How can I provide this optional param value for the
>   security service constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `@Optional()` decorator before the constructor parameter that should only be injected if there was a provider registered.

```
constructor(private http: Http,@Optional() private name: string)
```

You can read more about [Optional](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) here

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubo2ok?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide full example of providing value?

Comment: @user1765862 : check out the link in the answer

Comment: Obviously I'm missing something on your demo, I don't see how are you providing name to the injectible Car?

Comment: @user1765862 : Check now I have updated the demo code

Comment: Thanks, it's much more clear now. The only thing is that on my app I'm getting ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/core/src/di/reflective_injector ---------- Is it maybe related to angular5 version, since I'm using angular2?

Comment: I'ts wrong import  import ReflectiveInjector from @angular/core